# Get a polymorphic subclass given the superclass and polymorphic_identity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have sqlalchemy polymorphic subclasses, is there a way to to find a subclass given a superclass and polymorphic_identity?

eg:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'manager',
    }
```

is there a way to get the Engineer class like:

```
get_subclass(Employee, 'engineer')
```

I could compile my own dict of known subclasses, but I'm hoping to find a built way with sqlalchemy to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The base class's mapper has a `polymorphic_map` property which maps polymorphic identities to their respective mappers, and from there you can get the class.  So all you need is:

```
Employee.__mapper__.polymorphic_map['engineer'].class_
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a function in my project that might help you

```
def make_class_by_discriminator_dict(module_name, root_cls=object):
    result = {}
    clss = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[module_name], inspect.isclass)
    for _, cls in clss:
        if cls.__module__ == module_name and issubclass(cls, root_cls):
            try:
                discriminator = cls.__mapper_args__['polymorphic_identity']
                result[discriminator] = cls
            except (AttributeError, KeyError):
                pass
    return result
```

Now what you need is

```
make_class_by_discriminator_dict(module_name, Employee)['engineer']
```

Comment: not that this is necessary anyway, but fyi you could've avoided most of the inspection by iterating over `Employee.__subclasses__()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
mapping = {}
for mapper in class_mapper(Employee).polymorphic_iterator():
    mapping[mapper.polymorphic_identity] = mapper

...

# in a from-json function, where app_data["type"] is the discriminator
node_class = mapping[app_data["type"]].class_
```