# SQLAlchemy cascading polymorphic column updates

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a parent Employee table and a child Engineer table. From a client perspective I only want to interact with the Employee model. This is easily implemented for READ and DELETE, but issues arise when trying to UPDATE or INSERT.

The [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html) state:

> Warning
>
> Currently, only one discriminator column may be set, typically on the base-most class in the hierarchy. “Cascading” polymorphic columns are not yet supported.

So it would seem that by default this is not going to work. I'm looking for ideas on how to make this work.

Here's a complete test setup using postgres with psycopg2. The SQL might work with other SQL databases, but I have test any others.

**SQL script to create test database (testdb) and tables (employee, engineer):**

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
\c testdb;

CREATE TABLE employee(
  id    INT   PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
  name  TEXT,
  type  TEXT
  );

CREATE TABLE engineer(
  id            INT   PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
  engineer_name TEXT,
  employee_id INT REFERENCES employee(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

**Python test script:**

As-is the INSERT test will fail, but the DELETE will pass. If you change the code (comment/uncomment) to use the child Engineer model it will pass both cases.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
    Integer,
    Text,
    )

Base = declarative_base()

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text(), default='John')
    type = Column(Text, default='engineer')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type,
        'with_polymorphic': '*',
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id',
                ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(Text(), default='Eugine')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }


def count(session, Model):
  query = session.query(Model)
  count = len(query.all())
  return count

url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/testdb'
engine = sa.create_engine(url)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
Base.metadata.create_all()
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine)
session = Session()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  id=0
  print '#'*30, 'INSERT', '#'*30
  id += id
  # I only want to interact with the Employee table
  e = Employee(id=id)
  # Use the child model to see the INSERT test pass
  # e = Engineer(id=id)
  session.add(e)
  session.commit()
  print 'pass' if count(session, Employee) == count(session, Engineer) else 'fail'

  print '#'*30, 'DELETE', '#'*30
  # e = session.query(Employee).first()
  session.delete(e);
  session.commit();
  print 'pass' if count(session, Employee) == count(session, Engineer) else 'fail'

  session.flush()
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this through the sqlalchemy model definitions without having to use explicit controller code?

Thanks!

**Edit**
Well I'm not getting any love for this one. Anybody have ideas on how to accomplish this *with* controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using controller logic this can be accomplished by [getting the polymorphic subclass using the polymorphic identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696073/get-a-polymorphic-subclass-given-the-superclass-and-polymorphic-identity).

I'm adding two functions to encapsulate some basic logic.

```
def get_polymorphic_class(klass, data):
  column = klass.__mapper__.polymorphic_on
  if column is None:
    # The column is not polymorphic so the Class can be returned as-is
    return klass
  identity = data.get(column.name)
  if not identity:
    raise ValueError('Missing value for "' + column.name + '"', data)
  mapper = klass.__mapper__.polymorphic_map.get(identity)
  if mapper:
    return mapper.class_
  else:
    raise ValueError('Missing polymorphic_identity definition for "' + identity + '"')
  return klass

def insert(klass, data):
  klass = get_polymorphic_class(klass, data)
  e = klass(**data)
  session.add(e)
  session.commit()
  return e
```

Now I update `main` to use the `insert` function and everything works as expected:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  id=0
  print '#'*30, 'INSERT', '#'*30
  id += id
  e = insert(Employee, {'id': id, 'type': 'engineer'})
  print 'pass' if count(session, Employee) == count(session, Engineer) else 'fail'

  print '#'*30, 'DELETE', '#'*30
  session.delete(e);
  session.commit();
  print 'pass' if count(session, Employee) == count(session, Engineer) else 'fail'
  session.flush()
```

There's some extra code in my encapsulation for reusability, but the important part is doing `Employee.__mapper__.polymorphic_map['engineer'].class_` which returns the `Engineer` class so we can do a proper cascading INSERT.